# ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i have an import problem when executing my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
```

```
2021-10-06 22:27:14.064885: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-10-06 22:27:14.064974: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\breast-cancer-classification\train_model.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cancernet.cancernet import CancerNet
  File "C:\Data\breast-cancer-classification\cancernet\cancernet.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization' (C:\Users\Catalin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\normalization\__init__.py)
```

- Keras version: 2.6.0
- Tensorflow: 2.6.0
- Python version: 3.9.7

The library it is installed also with

```
pip install numpy opencv-python pillow tensorflow keras imutils scikit-learn matplotlib
```

Do you have any ideas?

[library path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qup45.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do *not* throw the whole of your code here as-is for an error happening in the 2nd line! Code here is supposed to be *minimal* - just enough to demonstrate the issue (edited).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using outdated imports for `tf.keras`. Layers can now be imported directly from `tensorflow.keras.layers`:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (
    BatchNormalization, SeparableConv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
)
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K


class CancerNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        model = Sequential()
        shape = (height, width, depth)
        channelDim = -1

        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            shape = (depth, height, width)
            channelDim = 1

        model.add(SeparableConv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=shape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channelDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        model.add(SeparableConv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channelDim))
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channelDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        model.add(SeparableConv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channelDim))
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channelDim))
        model.add(SeparableConv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=channelDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))

        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(256))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        return model

model = CancerNet()
```

Answer (score 38):

You should import **BatchNormalization** in following way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
from tensorflow.python.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
```

Comment: This answer would be worth additional documentation. Is the answer different than before because of a new version of TF, maybe? It would help future visitors to state that explicitly if so.